# How To Create A Custom Center Tab Button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here to recreate a custom center tab button, but I already have my tabbarcontroller setup in IB.  Can anyone help me do this?  The tutorial does it all through code so its difficult to follow.

http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All they're doing is creating a blank UITabBarItem, no image or name, simply a placeholder. They then put a UIButton with a custom image (i.e. the green camera button) on top of the UITabBar. Just go into interface builder and add a new TabBarItem and put a UIButton on top of it.

Comment: ya, But they do some other stuff to make sure it always appears and stuff.  Like how do I make a click on that unbutton act like a click on the tab bar?

Comment: You can call tabBar.selectedItem = 3 or whatever the index of the item under your button is, and it will seem like it's part of the tab bar. I don't really understand why it wouldn't always appear. The tutorial that you posted overcomplicates things a little in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, but in IB, I can't add a UIButton over the UITabBar, Xcode will not let me.  Do you know how I can do it via code instead?

Comment: Add one, then set the frame with code. button.frame = CGRectMake(whereYou, WantIt, sizex, sizey)

Comment: wherever you want to show the button, put any code related to the button in the viewController. That's where it would be relevant.

Comment: I Think I missed you in the chat.  BUt this is the tab bar so it should be displayed at all aspects of my app, therefore shouldn't it be in didfinishlaunching?

Comment: Then yes, you could put the code there. You should put the button's code wherever the container for your tab bar is.