# Custom UITabBarItem like in the Evernote app

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm trying to create a tab bar, where one of the tab items will open a modal view instead of opening a tab. I've already figured out how to do it, but I want that special tab item to look prominent, like in the Evernote tab bar. The Evernote "Add" button looks as if it is always in the selected state (while there is a regular selected tab in the tab bar at the same time).

I wonder - is it possible to achieve the same look (2 blue buttons at the same time) without overlaying custom buttons on top of the tab bar?

Thank you

[image: Evernote tab bar]

Comment: See post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809970/how-to-create-a-custom-center-tab-button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a tabbar item without contents
2. add a button above it with the plus image and set action to the tab bar action